# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pht.location_id' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

I have no table in my database in this name (location_id) but it gives me the error.

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'pht.location_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `locations`.*,
>   `location_id`.`location_trails_id` as `pivot_location_trails_id`,
>   `location_id`.`location_id` as `pivot_location_id` from `locations`
>   inner join `location_id` on `locations`.`id` =
>   `location_id`.`location_id` where `location_id`.`location_trails_id`
>   in (11, 13, 15, 16, 121, 123, 124, 181))",

I cannot find how to resolve it. Please Help me To resolve this issue. Thanks In advance.

Here is the code of my controller.

```
public function get($id)
{        
    $locations = LocationTrails::whereTrailId($id)->with('locations')->orderBy('ordered','ASC')->get();
    dd($locations);
    // $locations = Trail::findOrFail($id)->locations()->paginate($this->perPage);
    // dd($locations);

    $tdata = [];
    foreach($locations->items() as $location) {

        $hints = $location->hints;
        $hintsData = [];

        foreach($hints as $hint) {
            $hintsData[] = [
                'title' => $hint->title,
                'hint_text' => $hint->hint_text,
                'hint_solution_text' => $hint->hint_solution_text,
                'hint_image_path' => $hint->hint_image_path,
                'hint_video_path' => $hint->hint_video_path,
                'complexity_order' => $hint->complexity_order
            ];
        }

        $tdata[] = [
            'id' => $location->id,
            'title' => $location->title,
            'radius' => $location->radius,
            'latitude' => $location->latitude,
            'longitude' => $location->longitude,
            'rewards_points' => $location->rewards_points,
            'location_info_link' => $location->location_info_link,
            'hints' => $hintsData
        ];
    }

    $data = [];
    $data['data'] = $tdata;
    $data['meta']['paginator'] = $this->getPaginatorInfo($locations);

    return $data;
}
```

Here is my model of location

```
class Location extends Model
{
protected $table = 'locations';

protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'radius', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'rewards_points', 'location_info_link', 'location_order'
];


/********************* RELATIONS *********************/

public function trails()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Trail::class);
}

public function hints()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LocationHint::class);
}

public function location_trails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(LocationTrails::class,'location_id');
}
```

Here is my locationtrail model:

```
class LocationTrails extends Model
{
protected $table = 'location_trail';

protected $fillable = [
    'location_id', 'trail_id', 'ordered', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
];


/********************* RELATIONS *********************/

public function trails()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Trail::class,'trail_id');
}

public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class,'location_id');
}
```

Comment: what does `pht.location_id` relate to?

Comment: When the error is clearly related to `pht` I can't see anything posted about it?

Comment: pht is the name of database

Comment: you have error in your sql, thts why it is showing location_id as a table

Comment: How to resolve this error @iam

Answer (score 1):

problem is in your `LocationTrails` model. You define your method like `$this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');` so, laravel think `location_id` is a table name and the error thrown.

If it is one to many relationship.

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Location::class,'location_id');
}
```

If it is many to many relationship then you can see this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

same for your `trails()` method.

```
public function trails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Trail::class,'trail_id');
}
```

Comment: Its many to many relationship thats why i use belongs to many @MD.Sukel Ali

Comment: If it's many to many relationship then you need a relationship's joining table. You can go to my suggested link in the answer for proper instruction.